# How can I dynamically update className with React js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, classname

I have a Collection component and when I click on a div in this component, I want to change both the className of the Collection component and the className of the first sibling component after the Collection component.

With UseState, I could only change the className of the component I was in.

My Collection.js looks like this:

```
const Collection = () => {
  const [toggleClass, setToggleClass] = useState(false);

  function handleClick() {
    setToggleClass((toggleClass) => !toggleClass);
  }

  let toggleClassCheck = toggleClass ? "passive" : "active";

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className={`step ${toggleClassCheck}`}>
        <div className="atrium">
          <span>Collection</span>
        </div>
        <div className="content">
          <div
            className="moreThenOne"
            area="collectionTitle"
            onClick={handleClick}
          >
```

Can anyone help me on how to do the process I mentioned above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't quite understand what you want, but if you want to impact sibling of component "Collection" executing function inside of "Collection" you definitely should try "ref". Via useRef hook.

```
export const Collection = () => {
const [toggleClass, setToggleClass] = useState(false);
const divRef = useRef(null);

function handleClick() {
  divRef.current.nextSibling.classList.toggle('active');
  divRef.current.nextSibling.classList.toggle('passive');
  setToggleClass((toggleClass) => !toggleClass);
}

let toggleClassCheck = toggleClass ? 'passive' : 'active';

return (
<>
  <div className={`step ${toggleClassCheck}`} ref={divRef}>
    <div className="atrium">
      <span>Collection</span>
    </div>
    <div className="content">
      <div className="moreThenOne" onClick={handleClick}>
        CLICK ZONE
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</>
);
};
```

Comment: it really worked very well. I'm grateful, thank you very much ^^

Comment: This process works when switching from the first component to the second component. but when I write the same operations in the transition from the second component to the third, I do not get the desired result. How do I fix this?

Comment: yeah this is not about components it's more about DOM elements you change only DOM elements. Maybe you should watch your DOM structure to get things done using devtools of browser. And if it won't help you, you can write me contacts are here: https://muhammetnuramandurdyev.vercel.app/

Comment: I wrote the code in collection.js as you said, but when I write the same code for the next sibling component, the olculer.js component comes as "active" by default because there is a className change from the previous component.  Could you please help me here?

Answer (score 0):

The React components rerender, based on the state. So you sould use your state to define the className instead of a boolean.

When your state changes the component will re-render.

Try this:

```
   const Collection = () => {
  const [toggleClass, setToggleClass] = useState("active");

  function handleClick() {
    setToggleClass((prevState) => prevState == "active" ? "passive" : "active" );
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className={`step ${toggleClass}`}>
        <div className="atrium">
          <span>Collection</span>
        </div>
        <div className="content">
          <div
            className="moreThenOne"
            area="collectionTitle"
            onClick={handleClick}
          >
```

Comment: The way you are using state, will not re-render your components because the dependence of state is in the toggleClassCheck  variable, but, must be on the component

Comment: Thank you for the improvement. I made the fix. So how can I change the first sibling component className after the click event occurs?

Comment: The same way you did with the main <div>, you should create a new state with the className value you want and pass it on the className prop. If the className is the same you're already changing, just pass it's value to the prop.